I would rather have you doing something .... VS I would rather you did something
This is from a TV show, where a mom is trying to save her daughter from hooking, and they confront. At one point, the presenter said to the girl:

I would rather have you working with an exciting career in the fast food industry and living in a shelter with your son than I would have you hooking and him being raised by somebody else.

"I would rather have you working ....." seemed a complicated structure to me at first sight, because it seemed like a past version of "would rather" as in ""I would rather have done it earlier.";
however it also seemed like another structure "have someone doing something" as in "His story has us laughing so much every time he tells it."
So it seems to me the sentence is a combination of both structures, and meaning is present, and in simpler version, it would be something like this (in a shortened version): "I prefer that you work in fast food industry and live in shelter with your son instead of hooking and him getting raised by someone else."
So, is my understanding and analysis correct?

By the way, the verb confront is not used intransitively. One must confront something or someone.

@PaulTanenbaum, Thanks, I didn't know it. Should I write "They confront each other."?

Your version is almost correct. I would rather have you... means I would prefer to see you... The sense is:

I would prefer you to be working... in the fast food industry...

(assuming that she isn't working there at the moment, so it's a hypothetical situation.)
